# Spring jar has no package named "org.springframework.context.support"

Tags: spring, javac

after a compiler error with  `import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;`, I try to check spring jar, and I unarchive `spring-context-support-5.0.5.RELEASE`

```
$ pwd
/Users/apple/Desktop/springt/sp/spring-framework-5.0.5.RELEASE/libs/spring-context-support-5.0.5.RELEASE

$ tree -L 3
.
├── META-INF
│   ├── MANIFEST.MF
│   ├── license.txt
│   └── notice.txt
└── org
└── springframework
        ├── cache
        ├── mail
        ├── scheduling
        └── ui

7 directories, 3 files
```

there is not `org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` class file, and then I try to download any other spring release, still can not find this class.

what can I do?Where to find this class file?

Comment: What is your project setup? What IDE are you using ? Your problem seems to be a basic Spring setup issue, compiler does not see spring library jars at all, or so it seems.

Comment: checked it it's there...

Comment: Because that class is in the `spring-context.jar` and not `spring-context-support.jar`. Instead of manually hunting for jars and correct versions use Maven or Gradle to manage the dependencies for you.